# Bold Font in Linux

Tags: import

Re-Edit of the question for clarification: Blender only has one font and it doesn't turn bold. Any way to make easily make it bold?

So, I am using the RC1 release of 2.8 right now to make a logo for a possible client, but it looks like Blender only comes with a single font and it doesn't turn to bold. The logo includes bold font so I am wondering if there is any way to achieve this easily. Maybe another downloadeable font from somewhere else? Perhaps access to the fonts included in Linux?

Comment: Yes you need to specified the font folder in Linux for Blender to use(locate) your custom font and their family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While blender includes one font with its installation, you can use almost any font you can find. The most common font formats you find will be postscript, truetype or opentype. Look at the list of [formats supported by Freetype](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeType#File_formats).

Almost every website offering downloadable fonts offers a format that you can use with blender regardless of which system you are running. You can save these fonts anywhere and open them in blender.

Linux has [several packages](https://www.maketecheasier.com/install-hundreds-of-fonts-in-ubuntu/) of different fonts available to install that can easily be found by most programs, unfortunately blender doesn't look in these standard font directories, we need to open specific font files. To find the location of installed fonts, open a terminal and type `fc-list` to get a list of paths, font name and available styles.

Answer (score 3):

Different fonts can be loaded in the font tab which is shown below. Once you have selected the desired font files you can format the text.

[image]

You can change the formatting by switching to edit mode. Then you can select the text by moving the cursor with the left and right arrow keys to a desired position, now press and hold the shift key and move to the end position of the selection using the arrow keys. Once you have a selection the font menu allows to change the formatting.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here I am, answering my own question. I found out how to access the system fonts. It was under *user/share/fonts* and I figure that *Carlito Bold* may work for me. It worked in Blender with little issues.

Thanks for your help guys. I was able to glean some helpful usage information from your answers.